# Tooltip not displaying entire content for first two area charts

Tags: kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-asp.net-mvc, stacked-area-chart

Not sure where I'm doing wrong,I'm not able to load contents inside kendo chart on hover --only for the first two area charts from top.
The chart at the last is however loading all the template data inside the tooltips.
Please find the dojo link..

[Kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/otAku/4)

```
tooltip: {
                visible: true,                                 
                template:kendo.template(                     
                  '<div class="row">'+
                  '<div><h1>BRK-2212-002</h1> <h1>Breakdown</h1></div>'+                        
                   '<span class="border-box">Closed- #=dataItem#  </span>'+
                  '</div>'

                ) 

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually loads just fine. The problem is that text inside tooltip is `white` and therefore it looks empty.

If you add color for tooltip div

```
.row {
   color: black;
}
```

should be able to see text. Not quite sure why different `css` rules are being applied.